# My Python Array Resets Every Time I Run it

Tags: python

The array `journal` is set to empty automatically.

```
import os
import time
journal=[]
x=input()
for word in x:
    os.system('clear')
    print word,
else:
    print ""
    journal.extend(x)
    print journal
```

Comment: Where did you think it was going to get it from?

Comment: Yes computers do what they are told: `journal=[]`

Comment: What is the actual question? It's good to know that _"The array journal is set to empty automatically"_ though.

Comment: Also, your code makes no sense and therefore it is very difficult to understand what you wanted to achieve and therefore it is difficult to help you (or how to fix it). One thing I can say is that `else` usually follows an `if` and not a `for`.

Comment: @AGNGazer The else statement executes at the end of the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you run this code through the python interpreter your `array` (they're `lists` in python, `arrays` can be created using python modules) will be removed from memory when the script ends, you will need to save the values to a file or through some other method. You could try to add a `while` loop to the code in order to keep prompting the user to input until they quit the program.

As a side note; even if the `array` was still saved to local memory when the script ended, you are resetting the `list` in the first line `journal=[]`.

Comment: How would I make it so it saves, though, because deleting it would throw an error.

Comment: You can create a text file and store the variable within that file

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the information somehow if you’d like to have data persistency. Use the pickle module and create a file for the data to be stored and look up the docs for pickle for how to read and write.